# 3 squares in a circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Looking for the smallest circle which will hold three 1x1 squares. What is its radius?

By visualisation, I think that this is the optimal arrangement, but I'm unable to find the radius. Any hints would be appreciated.

[image]
<sub>(source: [Erich Friedman](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squincir/3.gif))</sub>

Comment: Related: http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/squincir/ ; r = 5 √17 / 16 = 1.288+

Comment: Take three of the vertices of the squares which meet the circle. The radius of the circle is the circumradius of the triangle they form.

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with the concept of circumradius and how to apply it in this circumstance

Comment: https://latex.artofproblemsolving.com/1/d/7/1d7cc49568f0bcc67ca49a02ce767e44fdfc235a.png I saw this formula but I don't see how we can find out the length of the sides of the triangle.

Comment: @WanyuTang: for the side lengths it is enough to apply the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The side lengths of the highlighted triangle are $1$, $\sqrt{2^2+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}$ and $\sqrt{2^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}$ by the Pythagorean theorem. Since its area is $1$, we have:
$$ \color{red}{R} = \frac{abc}{4\Delta} = \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{1\cdot\frac{25}{4}\cdot\frac{17}{4} }=\color{red}{\frac{5}{16}\sqrt{17}}\approx 1.28847. $$

Answer (score 1):

The shared edges form a "T" and the center of the circle lies a distance $x$ below the junction where all three shared edges come together.

Drawing a radius to the point where a bottom square touches the circle completes a right triangle in which

$r^2=1+(1-x)^2$

Drawing a radius to the point where the square touches the circle completes another right triangle in which

$r^2=(1/4)+(1+x)^2$

Thereby

$r^2=1+(1-x)^2=(1/4)+(1+x)^2$

and solving the last two members for $x$ gives $x=3/16$ (the quadratic terms cancel so there is only one root).  Plugging this into either expression for $r^2$ leads to

$r=\sqrt{425/256}=(5/16)\sqrt{17}$